# Tkinter Listbox selection by value (not index)

Tags: tkinter, listbox

I know how to set selection in Listbox by index but is it possible to do so by calling the value instead ?

I need this to select the corresponding values imported from a database when the form is recalled and I can't store the index in the database (has to be the text value).

Edit :
So far I'm using this to retrieve selection after the SQL Query :

`[my_listbox.selection_set(i) for i in[int(s) for s in (sql_result[0][76]).split(',')]]`

It's for multi-selection listbox BTW It works perfectly if the value stored in the database is the index (or a list of indexes) but I would like to do the same with the text VALUE of the index.

Thanks in advance.

N.

Comment: Show us what you have so far? And the code. So we understand better.

Comment: So far I'm using this to retrieve selection after the SQL Query : 

[my_listbox.selection_set(i) for i in[int(s) for s in (sql_result[0][76]).split(',')]]

It's for multi-selection listbox BTW

It works perfectly if the value stored in the database is the index (or a list of indexes) but I would like to do the same with the text VALUE of the index.

Comment: Update your question with this code.

Comment: Tkinter doesn't supply an option to do what you want, but you have all the tools you need to write your own function to do that.